# how can I make logo background fill header?

Tags: html, css

I am wondering how to accomplish this logo background found [here](http://www.degordian.com/site/services/)

if you notice the logo floated to the left and how the white "D" is on a red color background that fills the entire height of the header. I know how to float it and everything, I just need to know how to make a background color with a certain width to fill the entire height of the header like so. And by the way I am assuming  that there is no set height already for the header.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The height and width of the logo container is static. They have it set to 82px for both and then they just applied a red background via CSS and laid the transparent PNG over it.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever id or class your floated div is for the logo, simply apply a background color to that in CSS.

If you're looking for some sort of dynamic height application; set the html, body, and enclosing div elements to all have 'height:100%'.

Posting a sample of your code would help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try something like this ([fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/CU76y/2/)):

**HTML**:

```
<div id="Header">
    <img id="Logo" src="http://goo.gl/uDkk1X" />
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#Header {
    width: 600px;
    height: 60px;
    background: #333333;
}

#Logo {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    background: #666666;
}
```

As you can see, the image already has transparency, so any background color set to this `block` would render behind the actual image. Either that or put your `img` inside another container with a specified background color.